# Message notification Fetch MySql data

Tags: php

I'm using a script to display message notification to users , but my php file fetch data from database every time from the beginning of my database , what i want is for example i have in my database 100 messages , the script sent to everyone his message and that when new messages stored in database i don't want php file to begin fetching messages from 0 again i want it to start from message number 101 i mean every time from the newest messages
session_start();

```
$uid=$_SESSION['id'];    
        include_once('db.php');

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM message WHERE msg_to = $uid  ";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $result = array();
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {

            $sender_id = $row['msg_to'];

            $resultt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mem WHERE id= $sender_id");
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultt)) {

                  $result[] = array('sender_name' => $rows['username'], 'sender_age' => $rows['age'], 
                  'sender_photo' => $rows['image'], 'sender_language' => $rows['language'],
                  'sender_country' => $rows['country'], 'message' => $row['msg'] );
                  }

        }

    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [The mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` to limit the result of your database query. Or you could use a `WHERE` statement to select only rows with an ID that is greater than a certain value.

The exact syntax for `LIMIT` is:

```
SELECT   <columns>
FROM     <table>
ORDER BY <column>
LIMIT    <offset>,<amount>
```

See the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) for more information.

Comment: how can i use select only rows with an ID that is greater than a certain value. please help ,i try a lot of time but no success .

Comment: @user3423090 `SELECT … FROM … WHERE id > [certainvalue]`

Comment: i know but how can i determine that '[certainvalue]' for example if i give it ' $a = 4;' it will always begin fetching data from 'id=4' when the file was loaded .

Comment: @user3423090 Save it in the session for example. Or in a file. Or wherever you want.